# url rewrite in asp.net core for wordpress in blog route

Tags: wordpress, asp.net-core, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I implement shop with asp.net core and I want a blog route that fetches data from another server (WordPress)

for example, domain.com is on the IIS server with ASP.net core and domain.com/blog should be on Apache Server with WordPress

how can I do that?

Comment: You would need to configure your IIS server as a _reverse proxy_. The URL-path `/blog` is then "proxied" to the Apache server. But how is the Apache server accessed? Domain? IP address? Port?

Comment: I have access to the Apache server with the domain

Comment: @msn.secret based on your experience with this can you please answer this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76185459/can-we-handle-a-part-of-a-website-using-asp-net-while-the-other-part-is-wordpres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IIS ARR reverse proxy could achieve this thing. You could set an IIS reverse proxy rule like below:

```
           <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="blog/(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="http://test.blog.com/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

Comment: I have installed Application Request Routing, and added this rule to web.config also set idle timeout of app pool to zero based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/installing-application-request-routing-arr/install-application-request-routing
but does not work, academy.titana.ir is available but titana.ir/academy is not available

Comment: Since this is according to your production environment, we don't know your environment, you must troubleshoot it by yourself. I suggest you could also check this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to troubleshoot, if you still couldn't figure out why it doesn't work, I suggest you could create a Microsoft support ticket to let MSFT engineer to help you.

Comment: I remove / from the match tag and it fixed
<match url="blog(.*)" />

Comment: @brandoZhang can you please check this too. Thank you very much. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76185459/can-we-handle-a-part-of-a-website-using-asp-net-while-the-other-part-is-wordpres?